# Make @ConfigurationProperties properties partially mandatory

Tags: spring

Given the following simple (not nested) configuration properties class:

```
@ConfigurationProperties("env")
public class MyServiceProperties {
  private String anyProperty;
  private Boolean anyOther;
...
```

}

How can I make sure that *anyProperty* is mandatory, i.e. env.any-property must be set to startup the application? Is there any difference for *nested configuration property classes*?

Answer (score 12):

You can perform all kind of validations.

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("env")
public class MyServiceProperties {

  @NotNull
  @Min(5)
  private String anyProperty;

  // this is for nested objects
  @Valid
  @NotNull
  private FooNested fooNested;

  public static class FooNested{
     @NotNull
     private String someVal;
  }
}
```

You could also perform manual validation in setter

```
@Validated
@ConfigurationProperties("env")
public class MyServiceProperties {

   private String anyProperty;

   public void setAnyProperty(String anyProp){
      // just an example
      if(anyProp.lenght < 6){
         throw new RuntimeException();
      }
      this.anyProperty = anyProp;
   }
}
```